# My application immediately exits when i i press back button, dont wait for confirmation from user

Tags: android

when i press back button, application immediately exits and dont wait for confirmation from user "Are you sure ?"

Here is my onbackpressed code

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    super.onBackPressed();

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing Application")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    finish();
                    System.exit(0);
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();

}
```

anyone here who can help me

Comment: just add this in your `onBackPressed finish();
                    System.exit(0);`

Comment: @VishalYadav how to exit from background also ?

Comment: `android:autoRemoveFromRecents="true"` add this in `manifest`

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove `super.onBackPressed();` before the dialog appears

Try this way,

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

    new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
            .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
            .setTitle("Closing Application")
            .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    super.onBackPressed();
                }

            })
            .setNegativeButton("No", null)
            .show();

}
```

Comment: it exit from thwere but stays there in background app

Comment: how to exit from background also ?

Answer (score 1):

remove this line

```
 super.onBackPressed();
```

Comment: it worked but application remains stay in background when i click from there it starts again

Answer (score 0):

To remove the app from background also  u can use the below code.

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {

new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
        .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
        .setTitle("Closing Application")
        .setMessage("Are you sure you want to close this application?")
        .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                super.onBackPressed();
                moveTaskToBack(true);                          
                android.os.Process.killProcess(android.os.Process.myPid());
                System.exit(1);
            }

        })
        .setNegativeButton("No", null)
        .show();
```

}